# limited date in calendar - primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, calendar

I'm using primefaces calendar but I'm having a problem with the year.
The select component lists just the last (and next) 10 years, so between 2003 and 2023.
In a field of birthday it can be terrible..
Follow the print of the component. How can I fix it?

[image: print screen of calendar component]

Comment: Please do not yell "SOLVED" in title like as in an ordinary discussion forum. You're here on a Question&Answer site. Just post an answer, and when the time allows it, mark it accepted. This way the question would already appear differently in the listing which is interpretable as "solved".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I managed to fix this!

I just defined the attribute yearRange. The default value is yearRange="c-10:c+10"
So I put like this:

yearRange="c-70:c+10"